# How can I take cosine of a variable in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, components, trigonometry

I am trying to make a program that will find the x and y components of an applied force at an angle.  Here is what I have so far.  When I run it I get an error that basically says that you cannot take the cosine of a variable and that it has to be a real number.  How would I make this type of program work?

---

```
Import math
Angle = input("Enter angle:")
Force = input("Enter applied force:")
X = math.cos(angle)
Y = x * force
Print("The x component of the applied force is", y)
B = math.cos(angle)
A = b * force
Print("The y component of the applied force is", A)
```

Comment: Other than problems with capitalization, what's not working?

Comment: First issue I see, Python `input` is a `string` by default. You can't take the `cos()` of a string.

Comment: Yeah, sorry at the capitalization I’m doing this on an iPad... when I want to take the cosine/sine of a variable(which will be a integer inputted by the user) it says that it must be a real number? Not a string? Then how would I change it from a string?

Comment: @GarrettFong then you use `angle = float(input('enter angle: '))` to convert user input to a float so you can use it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's code after fixing capitalization and changing type of inputted values to floats:

```
import math
angle = float(input("Enter angle:"))
force = float(input("Enter applied force:"))
x = math.cos(angle)
y = x * force
print("The x component of the applied force is", y)
b = math.cos(angle)
a = b * force
print("The y component of the applied force is", a)
```

Comment: Thanks I was just confused on how to make the input into a float.  Thanks so much